# How can I change path of css and others in default.ctp in cake php?

Tags: cakephp

My cake php code in localhost/admin/app/webroot

And in default.ctp file

The code is like this
echo $this->Html->css('style');

For this it is load

< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/webroot/css/style.css" />

so its not loaded.

How can I gave full path here ?
Should I have to change .htaccess file for the same ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I gave you the answer to this in the previous question you posted, you need to set your document root to be app/webroot

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html

You need to follow that because you havent looked at it!

Comment: Configure::write('App.cssBaseUrl', 'css/'); chage path form core.php file

Answer (score 0):

You can put full path in first argument

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :

If we can add

Configure::write('App.base', '/admin/');

in bootstrap.php file then it works for me.

Thanks for your help.